# Sorting varchar field numerically in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a field `number` of type `varchar`. Even though it is of type `varchar`, it stores integer values with optional leading zeros. A sort orders them lexicographically (`"42"` comes before `"9"`). How can I order by numeric values (`"9"` to come before `"42"`)?

Currently I use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY number ASC
```

Comment: `number` is a string field, right? Because that's a lexicographical ordering.

Comment: you should just change the column type to int and use **zerofill** (if you want to keep 00100)

Comment: @ajreal, There is no benefit in using zerofill (nonstandard) as that will add more leading zeros while fetching that field. So that will not help in this case.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Store them as numeric values rather than strings. You've already discounted that as you want to keep strings like `00100` intact with the leading zeros.
2. Order by the strings cast as numeric. This will work but be aware that it's a performance killer for decent sized databases. Per-row functions don't really scale well.
3. Add a third column which is the numeric equivalent of the string and index on that. Then use an `insert`/`update` trigger to ensure it's set correctly whenever the string column changes.

Since the vast majority of databases are read far more often than written, this third option above amortises the cost of the calculation (done at `insert`/`update`) over all selects. Your selects will be blindingly fast since they use the numeric column to order (and no per-row functions).

Your inserts and updates will be slower but that's the price you pay and, to be honest, it's well worth paying.

The use of the trigger maintains the ACID properties of the table since the two columns are kept in step. And it's a well-known idiom that you can usually trade off space for time in most performance optimisations.

We've used this "trick" in many situations, such as storing lower-cased versions of surnames alongside the originals (instead of using something like `tolower`), lengths of identifying strings to find all users with 7-character ones (instead of using `len`) and so on.

Keep in mind that it's okay to revert from third normal form for performance provided you understand (and mitigate) the consequences.

Answer (score 84):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY CAST(field_name as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC
```

Comment: Is this going to be efficient for large databases?

Comment: @marcog: As mentioned in the answer by paxdiable, this will be a performance killer.

Comment: Even though it has performance issues it still works. Better than nothing.

Answer (score 42):

Actually i've found something interesting:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY LPAD(LOWER(mycol), 10,0) DESC
```

This allows you to order the field like:

```
1
2
3
10
A
A1
B2
10A
111
```

Comment: + 1 as this solution only solved perfectly for alphanumeric. How is the performance over a huge number of data? If your data has 10+ digits, it is wise to increase the LPAD length by more than 10.

Answer (score 27):

Trick I just learned. Add '+0' to the varchar field order clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY number+0 ASC
```

I now see this answer above. I am wondering if this is typecasting the field and an integer. I have not compared performance. Working great.

Comment: Oh yes. This is an old Perl trick too. I have another method of sorting varchar fields to get this type of result, and now I will be tempted to replace it with this rather obfuscated but easy WTDI.

Comment: +1 if the column data type is in string and the values will only be only in numeric. It will fails if the value is in numeric and alphabets

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY number + 0
```

Comment: So this way number will cast to int. Good idea !

Comment: I also used + 0.0 to get a float to sort my version field correctly. Thanks!

Comment: +1 if the column data type is in string and the values will only be only in numeric. It will fails if the value is in numeric and alphabets

Answer (score 7):

For a table with values like Er353,  ER 280, ER 30, ER36
default sort will give 
ER280
ER30
ER353
ER36

```sql
SELECT fieldname, SUBSTRING(fieldname, 1, 2) AS bcd, 
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(fieldname, 3, 9), UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY bcd, num;
```

the results will be in this order
ER30
ER36
ER280
ER353

Answer (score 3):

you can get order by according to your requirement my using following sql query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY ABS(mycol)
```

Answer (score 1):

given a column `username` containing `VARCHAR`'s like these:

```
username1
username10
username100
```

one could do:

```sql
SELECT username,
CONVERT(REPLACE(username, 'username', ''), UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS N
FROM users u
WHERE username LIKE 'username%'
ORDER BY N;
```

it is not cheap, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY number ASC
```

Should display what you want it to display.. looks like you're sorting it by `id` or `number` is not defined as `integer` at the moment.

Comment: did you set 'number' field as int or as varchar?

Comment: @wow Why is it a varchar? Can you change it or is it too late?

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL ORDER BY Sorting alphanumeric on correct order**

example:

```
SELECT `alphanumericCol` FROM `tableName` ORDER BY 
  SUBSTR(`alphanumericCol` FROM 1 FOR 1), 
  LPAD(lower(`alphanumericCol`), 10,0) ASC
```

output:

```
0
1
2
11
21
100
101
102
104
S-104A
S-105
S-107
S-111
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to keep numerics at a top, then order by alpha.

```sql
IF(name + 0, name + 0, 9999999), name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Rough and ready: order by 1*field_name