# MySQL ORDER BY not working for numbers

Tags: java, mysql

ORDER BY is not working properly for numbers,but it's working well if I give for columns containing alphanumeric or only characters. The code which I had given is,

```
dbResult = dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT Bid_Number,Vendor_Name,Vendor_Address,Amount,Tax_Percentage,Amount_Aftertax,Expected_Deliverydate,Vendor_Code FROM purchase_bid    where PE_Number='"+PENumber+"' ORDER BY Amount_Aftertax ASC");
```

if in my table I've `Amount_Aftertax` column values as,

> 840.0
>   780.0
>   3180.0
>   3810.0

by giving this code,i'm getting result according to this order

> 3180.0
>   3810.0
>   780.0
>   840.0

Hoping a reply please...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting varchar field numerically in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql)

Comment: Try `ORDER BY CAST(Amount_Aftertax AS UNSIGNED) ASC`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like your column type is still a *text* column, even though it contains numbers - so they're being sorted lexicographically. If you want them to be *treated* as numbers, you should make the *column* type a number too.

This doesn't just affect ordering, of course - *all* your code is likely to improve when you use appropriate types for your column. Just because you *can* stick pretty much any data in a string doesn't mean it's a good idea. Choose the data type which most closely matches the *real* data involved.

Additionally, you shouldn't specify the PENumber value like that - you should use a prepared statement, with a placeholder parameter in the SQL, which you provide the value for separately. Constructing SQL dynamically can lead to [SQL Injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com), as well as unnecessary conversions and a poor separation of code from data.

Answer (score 4):

`` SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY convert(`column_name`, decimal) DESC; ``

It should be something like this. You should first convert your varchar2 to decimal and do the ordering.

NOTE: Make sure to use `` instead of '' in the column_name.
Also you are better of converting the field type to number, use this if it's too late.

Answer (score 2):

it is working.. it is sorting alphabetically! You have declared this column as varchar, so it is considered data in it to be a string. So 3 is before 8 in alphabet and that is why it is before it.. if you want to sort numbers as numbers, not as a string, you need to change column type to int!

Answer (score 1):

The results are ordered in that fashion because it's treating it as text. '3' comes before '7', so anything beginning in '3', even if it's a higher number, will be ordered like a word.

Make sure your database has the field formatted as a numerical value - in your case, you'd want a `float` type, as you seem to have decimal places after your numbers. Once done, it'll format properly.