# Fetch data order by whole numbers instead of order by each digit of a number

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

When I am using ORDER BY in mysql query it's ordering by each digit of a number.

For ex: Using the normal ORDER BY in my query I am getting this result

```
101, 103, 104, 105, 12, 123, 125, 13, 131, 134
```

But my requirement is I should get the result like this:

```
12, 13, 101, 103, 104, 105, 123, 125, 131, 134
```

How can we do it in mysql query.

Django query example:

```
Foo.objects.filter(                                 
    Q(m_number__icontains=(request.GET['term']))
).filter(
    co_id = co_id,
    is_active=1
).values(
    'pk',
    'm_name',
    'm_number'
).order_by(
     'm_number'
)
```

How can I use the extra here ? The order by should work on m_number column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting varchar field numerically in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree viraptor answers.

I assume you could do it in Django, by using extra :

```
Foo.objects.extra(select={ 'd_field' : 'cast(the_column AS UNSIGNED)' }).extra(order_by=['d_field'])
```

But viraptor is right, it's better to convert the type of the column itself (else you would have to remember the same "hack" whenever your model is used)

Final clause should look like :

```
Foo.objects.filter( 
    Q(m_number__icontains=(request.GET['term'])) 
).filter( 
    co_id = co_id, 
    is_active=1 
).extra( 
    select={ 
        'int_m_number': 'cast(m_number AS UNSIGNED)', 
        'pk': 'pk' , 
        'm_number': 'm_number'
    } 
).extra( 
    order_by=['int_m_number'] 
)
```

Comment: Hey Raphel thanks for your response. Please check my question. Now I have added my code, and asked a question below that.

Comment: Replace .order_by('m_number') with :
.extra(select={ 'int_m_number' : 'cast(m_number AS UNSIGNED)'}).extra(order_by=['int_m_number'])

Comment: NOw its sowing error "Cannot resolve keyword 'int_m_number' into field"

Comment: Hum, try to remove .values([...]) clause so that final query looks like :

    Foo.objects.filter(                                 
        Q(m_number__icontains=(request.GET['term']))
    ).filter(
        co_id = co_id,
        is_active=1
    ).extra(
        select={ 'int_m_number' : 'cast(m_number AS UNSIGNED)'}
    ).extra(
        order_by=['int_m_number']
    )

Comment: And if you want to really to really restrict to a small fet of fields (which is a good idea), you can define them in the extra/select :

.extra( select={ 'int_m_number' : 'cast(m_number AS UNSIGNED)', 'pk':'pk', 'm_name':'m_name', 'm_number':'m_number'} )

Comment: @RaphaëlBraud: Better, edit your answer to add code from your suggestions in comments.

Comment: @RaphaëlBraud: Thanks a lot mate, your solution worked for me. Please add the solution to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is most likely stored as text rather than a number. You can use `... ORDER BY CAST(the_column AS UNSIGNED)` if you want to force the right order. But a better solution is most likely to just convert the type of the column itself.

Comment: Can we do it in django query. Sorry I can't edit the column structure because its a old one, and I need to change at lot of places.