# Mysql varchar fields with number not sorting well

Tags: php, mysql, varchar

I have little knowledge of mysql, I am importing a csv file with many numbers in the db, my developer changed the type of fields from INT to VARCHAR and my script that usually sort one fields by numeric descending no longer display the number in descending order well, the numbers are mix up, even if I use phpmyadmin and click on the column.

He mentioned to me that when he changed the numerical fields value to VARCHAR because the data was getting corrupted otherwise. He succeeded in importing the data but my display script is not working well anymore.

I am way over my head.

```
'AVGSEARCHES` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1406
```

Here is the sorting order:

9900
90
880
8100
74000
720
70

SELECT DISTINCT `KEYWORD`,`AVGSEARCHES` FROM  `traffic` WHERE STATUS='Y' ORDER BY  `AVGSEARCHES`  DESC

Comment: what did you try ? where is your query ?

Comment: why should the data get corrupted? When the data has really only numbers, then INT or BIGINT should be fine, what could be the biggest number? or are there leading zero digits (what I don´t thin when I look at the coloum name ;) )?

Comment: <?php $detail=$db->fetchAssoc($db->fireQuery("SELECT DISTINCT `KEYWORD`,`AVGSEARCHES` FROM  `traffic` WHERE STATUS='Y' ORDER BY  `AVGSEARCHES` DESC"));
             if(count($detail)>0){
           for($i=0;$i<count($detail);$i++){
?>

Comment: This used to work before he changed the data type from INT to varchar.

Comment: I do not have any leading zero, the max number would be 100 million I guess.

Comment: If are change the field type to INT then import data I only get 0 in it.

Comment: ok here is the sorting order hope this help

Comment: 9900
90
880
8100
74000
720
70

Comment: Why in the world would someone store integers in varchar columns? Can you change back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting varchar field numerically in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql)

Comment: This work but not in DESC order "SELECT DISTINCT `KEYWORD`,`AVGSEARCHES` FROM  `traffic` WHERE STATUS='Y' ORDER BY LENGTH(AVGSEARCHES),  AVGSEARCHES"

Comment: I have edited the query to include all the useful information i can think of currently. Please run it and put a sample of the output in **[Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com)** or somewhere else where i can see the results easily. Edit you question to include the pastebin link. don't give up yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

one way, is to make fixed length strings padded to the left with leading zeroes. prevents the use of the index for ordering but does get the job done. It would look neater if it was converted to a stored function.

Missing the 'trim'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT KEYWORD, AVGSEARCHES 
FROM traffic 
WHERE STATUS='Y' 
ORDER BY RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000', TRIM(AVGSEARCHES)), 11)  DESC
```

To confirm what is wrong please run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT KEYWORD, AVGSEARCHES, 
       CONCAT('!', AVGSEARCHES, '!') raw_avgs,
       LENGTH(AVGSEARCHES) avgs_raw_len,
       CONCAT('!', TRIM(AVGSEARCHES), '!') trim_avgs,
       LENGTH(TRIM(AVGSEARCHES))      avgs_len, 
       CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(AVGSEARCHES)) avgs_char_len, 
       RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000', TRIM(AVGSEARCHES)), 11) with_trim
FROM traffic 
WHERE STATUS='Y' 
ORDER BY RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000', TRIM(AVGSEARCHES)), 11)  DESC
```

Here is some sample output as supplied by the op:

```
Keyword                 AVGSearches   no_trim with__trim 
window valances         9900           009900     009900 
wood blinds             9900           009900     009900 
arch window shutters      90         00000090   00000090 
arched window shutters    90         00000090   00000090
```

which cannot be correct! The 'no_trim' and 'with_trim' columns should be 11 characters wide according to the query.

Hmm, i am starting to wonder what is actually in those AVGSearches column.

I have edited the query to tell me what is actually in that column.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work the sorting is still wrong I used phpMyAdmin 4.0.4 to run it

Comment: window valances  9900  009900  009900
wood blinds     9900  009900  009900
arch window shutters  90  00000090  00000090
arched window shutters  90  00000090  00000090