# order by in mysql should be same as sorted in excel?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

**Before sorting** in mysql

```
user
--------
2-0904-2
52
100
101
102
103
104
108
109
11
112
113
114
12
13
14
15
16
18
2
```

**After sorting** in mysql

```
user
--------
2-0904-2
52
100
101
102
103
104
108
109
11
112
113
114
12
13
14
15
16
18
2
```

**Expected result after sorting** as per excel

```
user
--------
2-0904-2
2
11
12
13
14
15
16
18
52
100
101
102
103
104
108
109
112
113
114
```

Comment: why `2-0904-2` should be on the top ?

Comment: Show your query please.

Comment: I tried sorting in excel and it came on top. even if it comes at the bottom no problems but rest of the numbers have to be sorted correctly. And the column is defined as character in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
order by cast(user as unsigned) asc
```

or

```
order by (0 + user) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting string fields. To sort them using numeric comparison you need to cast them to integer.

Example:
`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY CAST(field_name as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC`

Although consider changing your field type since its an overhead for your queries to cast the field during sorting. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4686934/4195195)