# Besides Asc/Desc, Any other way to use Mysql Order By?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Sorry i was unable to ask my question properly, now i try to explain what i want  to ask.

for example i have 15 rows in mysql table with uniquenumber (other than primary key ID)

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

now if i use

```
SELECT * FROM info order by uniquenumber asc;
```

i will get results something like

```
1,10,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

however i want

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

how can i do this in mysql? thanks

Comment: What datatype of your uniquenumber column?

Comment: `order by CAST(uniquenumber  AS int)` . default order will be ascending . you don't need to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Cast unique number with type `varchar(255)` to `INT` type

```
SELECT * FROM info order by CAST(uniquenumber AS INT) ASC
```

Comment: change your table schema

Answer (score 0):

Make the column mysql data-type `Integer`(or any other numeric data-type), it would solve the problem.

Order by behaves this way due to string ordering.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: what command i should use to safely change datatype of column uniquenumber?

Comment: make the column primary key or part of uniqueness(composite key) which makes the column unique

Comment: @Maria Jones: You should be able to use `alter table` to change a column's type: `ALTER TABLE info MODIFY uniquenumber INT NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that, depending on the desire you have to work, most simple is make an operation (+0 for exmaple) to the value, this converts the varchar in a numeric value at order purposes,

`SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY uniquenumber+ 0 ASC`

You can do a conversion by some numerical function

`SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY ABS(uniquenumber) ASC`

`SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY CAST(uniquenumber as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC`

Yo my use the LPAD function [here description](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php)

If you assume that your table should have non-numeric data (because is a `varchar(255)`) you should make anything substring conversion ([See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)). For example AAA111, AAA112 or 111AAAA, 112AAAA etc..

`select uniquenumber,substring(uniquenumber, X, Y) as param1` and `CONVERT(SUBSTRING(uniquenumber, X, Y),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS param2 from info  order by param1,param2;`

See this question [Shorting Varchar field numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql)