# How to sort an alphanumeric column in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a column with values like below after **ordering** by it's column name **(equipment_no)** in **ASC** and was wondering how to sort it properly as shown in the next list.

```
SELECT equipment_no FROM fas_details WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'T%' ORDER BY equipment_no
```

Please do tell me your suggestions. Thank you.

**How mysql sorts**

```
T  - AG - 01
T  - AG - 02
T  - AG - 07
T  - AG - 08
T  - AG - 09
T  - AG - 10
T  - AG - 100
T  - AG - 101
T  - AG - 102
T  - AG - 103
T  - AG - 104
T  - AG - 11
T  - AG - 12
T  - AG - 13
```

**How I want it to be**

```
    T  - AG - 01
    T  - AG - 02
    T  - AG - 07
    T  - AG - 08
    T  - AG - 09
    T  - AG - 10
    T  - AG - 11
    T  - AG - 12
    T  - AG - 13
    T  - AG - 100
    T  - AG - 101
    T  - AG - 102
    T  - AG - 103
    T  - AG - 104
```

Comment: What you are looking for is something called "natural sort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to sort the equipment_no in ascending alphabetic order while considering the numeric part of equipment ordering too.

```
SELECT equipment_no FROM fas_details WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'T%' ORDER BY substring(equipment_no,1,9), substring(equipment_no,10)*1
```

I assumed the first 9 characters of equipment_no are alphabets, while remaining characters are numeric characters. Multiplying the numeric substring by 1 forces it to a number.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Order By CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no,'-',-1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

or you can try using RIGHT like

```
CAST(RIGHT(equipment_no, (CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(equipment_no),0))-1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: `CHARINDEX` is a `sql-server` function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring_index` function to get the number from string and then cast it to unsigned integer in order by :

```
 SELECT equipment_no FROM fas_details WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'T%' 
 ORDER BY cast(substring_index(equipment_no,'-',-1) as unsigned)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do this is to sort by your numeric token. It can be obtained using [SUBSTRING](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php) function (your structure seems fixed).

However, performance is not very good and the best option is to actually store that number in a separate column. Storage can be done directly by your application or [using auto generated columns](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/).

More details about your question can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql).

Comment: Thank for the idea, I will definitely keep that in my mind next time I implement something like this

Answer (score 0):

As the difference only in the last digits, we can be achieved it by

`ORDER BY LENGTH(equipment_no), equipment_no;`

Here it will order the results first by the length of the string in ascending order and then by that string.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM fas_details
ORDER BY LENGTH(equipment_no), equipment_no;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/614851/1)

In your answer the result is sorting down by the entire string. So when you order a string, for eg: `2` and `10`, `10` will come first. So just order by length of the string first.
*So you may have to change your sql query like below.*

**Query**

```
SELECT equipment_no 
FROM fas_details 
WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'T%' 
ORDER BY LENGTH(equipment_no), equipment_no;
```

**Result**

```
+---------------+
|  equipment_no |
+---------------+
| T  - AG - 01  |
| T  - AG - 02  |
| T  - AG - 07  |
| T  - AG - 08  |
| T  - AG - 09  |
| T  - AG - 10  |
| T  - AG - 11  |
| T  - AG - 12  |
| T  - AG - 13  |
| T  - AG - 100 |
| T  - AG - 101 |
| T  - AG - 102 |
| T  - AG - 103 |
| T  - AG - 104 |
+---------------+
```