# Sorting rows in SQL statement by numeric value is not taking decimals

Tags: php, sql

THE SQL Statement below sorts my results somewhat correctly but its not taking decimal point into consideration... how do I do this?

37.5 should be at the top.

SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "win_percentage" ORDER BY meta_value DESC

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 417
            [post_id] => 59
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 9.3023255814
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 419
            [post_id] => 62
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 6.66666666667
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 425
            [post_id] => 64
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 37.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 433
            [post_id] => 68
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 36.5079365079
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 421
            [post_id] => 58
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 32.8767123288
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [meta_id] => 423
            [post_id] => 63
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 16.6666666667
        )

)
```

Comment: What type of field is meta_value? Float, decimal, or varchar?

Comment: It looks like a string sort...

Comment: its varchar this is all within wordpresses meta so varchar is pretty much forced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR is a string variable type so it's sorting as if it's a string. 6 comes after 3 in a string, so when sorting DESC it'll appear first.

If you want this particular column to be treated as a float/decimal for sorting purposes you can use something like the following:

`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "win_percentage" ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS FLOAT) DESC`

Or whichever numerical type the database you're using has: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp