# Custom sort function for yii2 GridView

Tags: php, sorting, gridview, yii2

I've got a column of data (call it "ranking") that contains something like "1st", "2nd", "5th", "21st", "23rd", etc.  I'm using GridView to display the data, but when I sort by "ranking", I get "21st" between "1st" and "2nd" -- which makes sense lexicographically but is not what I want.

Is there a place in GridView, or ArrayDataProvider, or somewhere, where I can specify a custom sort function for that column, preferably a function I can write myself?

This column is not being stored in the database -- it's being computed based on the user's view.  This isn't an issue of how the data is stored in the database, but how it's displayed.  My issue is not on the model side, it's on the view side.

For example, say I display something like this in GridView:

```
 ORDER  SURNAME
   1st  Washington
   2nd  Adams
  19th  Hayes
  20th  Garfield
```

When the user tries to sort on "SURNAME", it becomes

```
 ORDER  SURNAME
   2nd  Adams
  20th  Garfield 
  19th  Hayes
   1st  Washington
```

And then if the user tries to sort on "ORDER", it becomes

```
 ORDER  SURNAME
   1st  Washington
  19th  Hayes
   2nd  Adams
  20th  Garfield
```

How can I make it so that when the user clicks on "ORDER" I get the first result and not the last?

Comment: can you provide your filter condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting varchar field numerically in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql)

Comment: soju: The column is not stored in the database, but instead it's being computed based on the user's view.

Comment: Naisa: I don't know what you mean by filter condition.  Can you be more specific?