# Sorting varchar field containing time numerically

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, date, datetime

I'm using a varchar field to store a time notation (format: 00:00).
How'd I sort results on this field, so that eg 08:00 comes before 10:00?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: This will be helpful -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be storing the data as [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) but you can always [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the [date time literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) on-demand:

```
ORDER BY CAST(thetime AS TIME)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, as well as ORDER BY ABS(thetime).
(btw: not voting up as my reputation still won't let me)

Answer (score 0):

Use [TIME_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_time_format.asp) function in your `ORDER BY` clause

assuming your column is named `thetime` and is always expressed as 24-hours format `hours:minutes` (23:43)

```
ORDER BY TIME_FORMAT(thetime, '%H:%i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an issue.  `'08:00'` is less than `'10:00'`.

You don't have the problem because you have zero-padded the string.  This works for up to `'99:59'`.  If you need three-digit hours, then you need to store an addition `0` for the hour:  `'008:00'' and`'010:00'`.

Of course, you can also use a `TIME` data type.  That would generally make sense, but it is limited in its range and it stores sub-minute parts for the time (so under some circumstances, it might not be a perfect fit for your needs).