# ORDER BY not working properly with UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, union, union-all

I have 2 tables t1 and t2 as follows

[image]

[image]

I want to select the results from both the tables with a UNION and sort on qty column. The query that I have written is

```
(SELECT * FROM t1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM t2)
ORDER BY qty ASC;
```

That gives me the below result

[image]

Can some 1 tell me what is going wrong here? As per the query I should get qty column sorted in ascending order. I have also tried

```
(SELECT * FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2)
ORDER BY qty ASC;
```

No luck with that either. If I do sort with id or item it works perfectly fine. This is really frustrating. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us the DDL for the tables?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Sorting varchar field numerically in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql)

Try

```sql
(SELECT * FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2)
ORDER BY CAST(qty as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evangelica, that worked. I've been breaking my head over this since hours but was not able to figure out the issue. Obviously this is the test data that I have provided but my real  query is really huge and complex so was not sure where the issue was. Turned out that 2nd table in my union was having a varchar data type and first 1 is having INT data type.