# Mysql varchar sorting

Tags: mysql

I have a filed **parameter_value** of type **varchar**. Even though it's type varchar, it stores integer,decimal and alphanumeric, special character values. I want to sort it by numerically.
e.g.

```
0.001
0.002
3
3.1
4
4.3
4.9 and so on.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting varchar field numerically in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql)

Comment: `ORDER BY column_name + 0`. This wiil cause implicit datatype convertion and correct, by numeric value, sorting. All non-numeric values will be treated as zero.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65a0e2b1abc0121775b9ac80495cd548

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY parameter_value + 0;`

For Example:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    Id int,
    name Varchar,
    price Varchar
);


INSERT INTO product
VALUES (11, 'abc', '100.5');

INSERT INTO product
VALUES (12, 'adc', '97.2');

INSERT INTO product
VALUES (13, 'arc', '104.5');

select * from product order by price +0;
```

Output:

```
12|adc|97.2
11|abc|100.5
13|arc|104.5
```

This would be helpful for sorting the numeric values of varchar type column.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the answer with detail.

Answer (score -2):

You can use ORDER BY ASC clause.

Eg:

```
SELECT * from TableName ORDER BY CAST(ColumnName AS DECIMAL) ASC
```

I tried to run the below in my local,

select * from Sort order by CAST(ColumnName AS DECIMAL) asc;

And the result is,

[image]

Comment: You forget that the datatype of the column is string one.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it will sort based on the value.

Comment: No. Create a fiddle and look.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: You are right. tried cast(Title as DECIMAL) then it sorted correctly. Thanks for the clarification